# Groovy-grails Mocking issue. Unable to Mock

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, junit, mocking

I have a service class method in my grails porject which uses a helper class to fetch the response as xml. The xml is then send out as the response of the service class method.

ServiceClass:-

```
class ItemService{
def getItem(Number) {
        def HelperClass helper = new HelperClass()
        def responseXml = helper.getMessage(Number)                 
        return responseXml
    }
}
```

I writing a test case for this method. In my test case, i wish to mock

```
    def responseXml = helper.getMessage(Number)
```

The test case that i have written so far is:

```
class ItemServiceTest extends GroovyTestCase {
public final void testFindItem(){
        def service = new ItemService()

        def xml = "<Item><Number>123</Number></Item>"

        def mockJobServiceFactory = new MockFor(HelperClass)
        mockJobServiceFactory.demand.getMessage{ def str ->
            return xml
        }
        service.getItem().HelperClass =  mockJobServiceFactory.proxyInstance()

        def item = service.getItem()("123")
        assertNotNull(item)
    }
```

but still, the mock does not return the xml that I speicified in the test case.
Any problems that you see in the above approach?...Advance Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you mock objects with [`MockFor`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/mock/interceptor/MockFor.html), you need to surround the code that uses the mock in a `use` closure.  Try this:

```
def service = new ItemService()

def xml = "<Item><Number>123</Number></Item>"

def mockJobServiceFactory = new MockFor(HelperClass)
mockJobServiceFactory.demand.getMessage{ def str ->
    return xml
}

mockJobServiceFactory.use {
    def item = service.getItem()("123")
    assertNotNull(item)
}
```

Comment: But I do have some test cases where I did not use the 'use closure' and followed the methodology that I mentioned earlier. But, mocking worked correctly in those cases. Seems something is strange here

Comment: The line `service.getItem().HelperClass =  mockJobServiceFactory.proxyInstance()` is wrong.  You can't assign something to the value or class of a method's local variable.  In other cases you might be able to manually inject a proxy, but to mock a local variable, you need to use the closure.

Comment: Makes Perfect sense. Thank you Sir.